# Change color mainbutton if subbuttons are green

Tags: javascript, html

Have a mainbutton with two subbuttons. If checkbox behind subbutton is checked then subbutton change from red to green. If both subbuttons are green then mainbutton should change from red to green

tried to create a script to do this. If I run the code without function "ChangeGCPOD" then the subbuttons change color if checkbox is checked. But with function "ChangeGCPOD" the subbuttons don't change color and also the mainbutton does not change color

```js
 //  If checkbox is checked equipment is NOT in run, then background row    equipment change to grey and Color button from red to green-->
    function ChangeRowColor(chkrow, row, cel, btn) {
      var varrow = document.getElementById(row);
      var varcel = document.getElementById(cel);
      var varColor = "#E3CEF6";
      var varColor2 = "Yellow";
      if (chkrow.checked == true) {
        varColor = "Grey";
        varColor2 = "Grey";
        document.getElementById(btn).style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      } else {
        document.getElementById(btn).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }
      varrow.style.backgroundColor = varColor;
      varcel.style.backgroundColor = varColor2;
      ChangeGCPOD();
    }

    function ChangeGCPOD() {
      var varE1 = document.getElementById('b_echo_01');
      var varE2 = document.getElementById('b_echo_02');
      var varColor = "red";
      var varColor2 = "green";

      if (varE1.style.backgroundColor = varColor2 && varE2.style.backgroundColor = varColor2) {

        document.getElementById('gcpod').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('gcpod').style.backgroundColor = 'red';

      }
    }
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 160px;
  border: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color: red;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.green,
input.green {
  background: green;
}

.buttonsmall {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color: white;
}

.buttonsmall:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <!-- Create extra space -->
  <p><br><br></p>
  <!-- Create extra space -->
  <p><br></p>

  <body>
    <!-- Create extra space -->
    <p><br><br></p>
    <!-- Create extra space -->
    <p><br></p>
    <div id="GC">
      <button id="gcpod" class="buttonsmall" style="height:20px;width:60px">
     </div>
      <div id="Echo_O01_button">
        <table style="width:20%;margin-left:50px;">
          <colgroup>
            <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
            <!--<col style="background-color:yellow"> -->
          </colgroup>
          <tr id="rowA">
            <td width="20%"><input type="button" id="b_echo_01"   class="buttonsmall" style="height:20px;width:60px"     onclick="showOrHide('Echo_O01')">
            </td>
            <td width="40%"><b>Echo555_O01</></td>
                <td  width="15%"></td> 
             <td  id="celA" width="15%" bgcolor="yellow"><input     type="checkbox" name="notinrun6" id="chkrowA"     onclick="ChangeRowColor(this,'rowA','celA', 'b_echo_01')"/></td>
                <td  width="10%"></td> 
              </tr> 
              </table>
              </div> <!-- Close Div Echo_O01_button --> 
               <!--  <p><br></p> -->
             <div id="Echo_O02_button">
         <table style="width:20%;margin-left:50px;" >
         <colgroup>
            <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
            <!--<col style="background-color:yellow"> -->
          </colgroup>
          <tr id="rowB">
            <td  width="20%"><input type="button" id = "b_echo_02" class="buttonsmall" style="height:20px;width:60px" onclick="showOrHide('Echo_O02')">      
            </td>
            <td  width="40%"><b>Echo555_O02</></td>
            <td  width="15%"></td> 
          <td  id="celB" width="15%" bgcolor="yellow"><input type="checkbox" name="notinrun6" id="chkrowB" onclick="ChangeRowColor(this,'rowB','celB', 'b_echo_02')"/></td>
             <td  width="10%"></td> 
          </tr> 
          </table>
          </div> <!-- Close Div Echo_O02_button --> 
      </body>
    </html>
```

expect to change color mainbutton if both subbons are green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your logic is correct, just the condition is wrong, you use `=` not `==` in the line `if (varE1.style.backgroundColor = varColor2 && varE2.style.backgroundColor = varColor2)`

```js
 function ChangeRowColor(chkrow, row, cel, btn) {
      var varrow = document.getElementById(row);
      var varcel = document.getElementById(cel);
      var varColor = "#E3CEF6";
      var varColor2 = "Yellow";
      if (chkrow.checked == true) {
        varColor = "Grey";
        varColor2 = "Grey";
        document.getElementById(btn).style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      } else {
        document.getElementById(btn).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }
      varrow.style.backgroundColor = varColor;
      varcel.style.backgroundColor = varColor2;
      ChangeGCPOD();
    }

    function ChangeGCPOD() {
        var varE1 = document.getElementById('b_echo_01');
        var varE2 = document.getElementById('b_echo_02');
        var varColor = "red";
        var varColor2 = "green";
        
        if (varE1.style.backgroundColor == varColor2 && varE2.style.backgroundColor == varColor2) {
            document.getElementById('gcpod').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('gcpod').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        
        }
      }
```

```css
table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    button {
      height: 40px;
      width: 160px;
      border: 4px;
      border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
      border-color: red;
      color: yellow;
      padding: 12px 15px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    button.green,
    input.green {
      background: green;
    }

    .buttonsmall {
      background-color: #FF0000;
      border: 4px;
      border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
      border-color: white;
    }

    .buttonsmall:hover {
      background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
     <body  >
      <!-- Create extra space -->
    <p><br><br></p>
   
    <!-- Create extra space -->
     <p><br></p>

    <body>
      <!-- Create extra space -->
      <p><br><br></p>
      <!-- Create extra space -->
      <p><br></p>
      <div id="GC">
       <button id="gcpod" class="buttonsmall" style="height:20px;width:60px">
     </div>
      <div id="Echo_O01_button">
        <table style="width:20%;margin-left:50px;">
          <colgroup>
            <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
            <!--<col style="background-color:yellow"> -->
          </colgroup>
          <tr id="rowA">
            <td width="20%"><input type="button" id="b_echo_01"   class="buttonsmall" style="height:20px;width:60px"     onclick="showOrHide('Echo_O01')">
            </td>
            <td width="40%"><b>Echo555_O01</></td>
                <td  width="15%"></td> 
             <td  id="celA" width="15%" bgcolor="yellow"><input     type="checkbox" name="notinrun6" id="chkrowA"     onclick="ChangeRowColor(this,'rowA','celA', 'b_echo_01')"/></td>
                <td  width="10%"></td> 
              </tr> 
              </table>
              </div> <!-- Close Div Echo_O01_button --> 
               <!--  <p><br></p> -->
             <div id="Echo_O02_button">
         <table style="width:20%;margin-left:50px;" >
         <colgroup>
            <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
            <!--<col style="background-color:yellow"> -->
          </colgroup>
          <tr id="rowB">
            <td  width="20%"><input type="button" id = "b_echo_02" class="buttonsmall" style="height:20px;width:60px" onclick="showOrHide('Echo_O02')">      
            </td>
            <td  width="40%"><b>Echo555_O02</></td>
            <td  width="15%"></td> 
          <td  id="celB" width="15%" bgcolor="yellow"><input type="checkbox" name="notinrun6" id="chkrowB" onclick="ChangeRowColor(this,'rowB','celB', 'b_echo_02')"/></td>
             <td  width="10%"></td> 
          </tr> 
          </table>
          </div> <!-- Close Div Echo_O02_button --> 
      </body>
    </html>
```